# bootstrap radio buttons with custom text-field - unable to type inside text-field

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a custom text input to a group of radio buttons. I want the user to be able to write a custom text inside the text-field. While the text-field shows up correctly, I am unable to type inside the text-field. Any idea on how to fix this?

I am using bootstrap and this is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> Other <input type="text" name="other"> 
  </label>

</div>
```

My fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nLxgdhaf/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that selecting the input triggers bootstrap's `radio` button selection, which overrides your `textbox` selection. A quick hacky solution would be to disable the bootstrap functionality via `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropogation()`, focus on the textbox, and then select the radio button via js. Here's a working example:

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="other"]').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

/* console.log(this.previousElementSibling.checked) */

this.previousElementSibling.checked = true

document.querySelectorAll('label').forEach(function (el) {
 el.classList.remove('active')
 el.classList.remove('focus')
})

this.parentElement.classList.add('active')
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> Other <input type="text" name="other"> 
  </label>
  
</div>
```